# For which $m,n$ is the graph $K_{m,n}$ integral?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

A graph is *integral* if the eigenvalues of its adjacency matrix are all integers. For which integers $m$ and $n$ is $K_{m,n}$, the complete bipartite graph on $m$ and $n$ vertices, integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the adjacency matrix of $K_{m,n}$. Now up to reordering of rows and columns $A$ must look like
\begin{equation*}
    A = \begin{bmatrix}
           0&\dots&0&1&\dots&1 \\
           \vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
           0&\dots&0&1&\dots&1 \\
           1&\dots&1&0&\dots&0 \\
           \vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
           1&\dots&1&0&\dots&0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
where the blocks of ones have dimension $m \times n$. Now let's calculate some successive powers of $A$. This can done quickly by recalling that the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^n$ represents the number of distinct paths of length $n$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.
\begin{equation*}
    A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
           m&\dots&m&0&\dots&0 \\
           \vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
           m&\dots&m&0&\dots&0 \\
           0&\dots&0&n&\dots&n \\
           \vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
           0&\dots&0&n&\dots&n \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \quad
    A^3 = \begin{bmatrix}
           0&\dots&0&mn&\dots&mn \\
           \vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
           0&\dots&0&mn&\dots&mn \\
           mn&\dots&mn&0&\dots&0 \\
           \vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
           mn&\dots&mn&0&\dots&0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
So from this we see that $A$ has minimal polynomial $A^3-mnA$. The minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial, and all the roots of the characteristic polynomial (eigenvalues) are roots of this minimum polynomial too ([Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)), so $A$ has integer eigenvalues exactly when the roots of $A^3-mnA$ are integers. The roots of $A^3-mnA$ are $0$ and $\pm\sqrt{mn}$, so we can conclude that $K_{m,n}$ is integral exactly when the product $mn$ is a square.